# Cannot set property 'quantity' of undefined and it say additems is not define

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
...
const cartReducer = (state=initialstate,action)=>{
    
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
            let addedItem = state.array.find(item=> item.id === action.payload.id)
           
            
            let  existed_item= state.addedItems.find( item => action.id === item.id)
           
            if(existed_item)
            {
                addedItem.quantity += 1 
                return{
                    ...state,
                    total: state.total + addedItem.price 
                }
            }
            else{
                addedItem.quantity = 1;
               
                let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price 
                
                return{
                    ...state,
                    addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem],
                    total : newTotal
                }
                
            }
            
            default:
                return state;
            }
            
        }
  
        export default cartReducer;
...
```

i have a error in react-redux that the addItems is not define but i define that in let scope
and error is shown as
TypeError: Cannot set property 'quantity' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Check what inside `addedItem` variable `console.log(addedItem)`

```js
let addedItem = state.array.find(item=> item.id === action.payload.id)
```

`state.array.find` maybe returning `undefined` because no item match with condition `item.id === action.payload.id`

Try check and add conditition

```js
if (addedItem) {
 ....
}
```